Installing 24.04 from a single internal SSD as an inital bootable without the option of external drives for Ubuntu Live session
Here's the challenge.
I want to install 24.04 LTS Desktop on my machine.
I can't access the BIOS options to allow to boot from an external device (USB, portal drive) nor from network.
I've created a bootable on the internal drive using another Ubuntu machine.
I can run the initial Ubuntu live session on the computer and play around with the "try Ubuntu"
When I launch the installation process I'm blocked when I need to start assigning the via the "Manual Partition".
I can't assign the /Boot and /root devices because there is no space on the SSD.
The installation GUI see the SSD as a DVD.
When I launch the install error is unable to unmount the defined drives to do the final insatall.
My question:
Is there a way while creating the bootable SSD to partition it?
The idea would be to create a boot partition (size is about 7 GB) with the Ubuntu Live ISO and have the rest of the drive (approx 350GB) free. This would allow to later assign the /root and /boot as well a the swap so that the install can be done.
I'm using Etcher (BalenaEtcher) to create the bootable with the official Ubutnu ISO but there are no options to partition this bootable drive...
Thank you for your support.

Do not understand not having access to boot USB. How are you going to fix Windows or whatever system you have installed now? Or is this not your system, work or school,  and you really then should not be modifying it. What brand//model system?

Hi Oldfred, I'm doing a fresh install. I took the drive out of my EliteBook HP 8560p and mounted it another ubuntu machine. From there I wiped it and created a bootable drive with Ubuntu 24.04 iso on it. I then put it back in the HP 8560P switched on and the Ubuntn live session works just fine.

On one of my drives, I created a second FAT32 partition of about 6GB  and moved boot,esp flags to it. Then extracted ISO into it and booted in UEFI mode. I had created FAT32 for install's ESP and / (root). You do not need /boot partition unless using LVM, and some like swap partition, but default now is swap file. I then moved boot,esp flags back to install's ESP and install then booted. But I normally just install grub and directly boot ISO using grub's loopmount. But that is now after a full install. Only with older small flash drives did I just install grub & ISO(s).
